# PHP unlink funtion doesn't work and can't delete files from folder

Tags: php

here's the code where i can delete row of data from database but unlink function doesn't working properly. it deletes the other file instead of selected file to delete.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
   @$box=$_POST['num'];
   while (list ($key,$val)=@each ($box)) {    
       mysqli_query($con,"select file from upload where id=$file");  
       unlink("file_folder/$file");  
       mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM upload where id=$val" ); 
   } 
} ?>
```

Form (Update)

```
    <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
   <td><button type='button" name='add' >Add</button></td> 
    <td><input type='submit' id="b2" name='delete' class="dlbtn" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Delete?')" /></td> 
</tr> 

<table> 
<tr> 
<th><input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this);" /></th> 
<th>File name</th> 
<th>Description</th> 
</tr>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not suppress errors when calling methods with the `@` operator. If something goes wrong you want to know about it and will need to take corrective action, display a useful message for the user, log the problem, or all that and more. It also makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated if you ignore errors that are trying to point out serious problems.

Comment: Can you show what your form/select looks like..?

Comment: <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<td><button type='button" name='add' >Add</button></td>
<td><input type='submit'  id="b2" name='delete' class="dlbtn" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Delete?')" /></td>
</tr>
<table>
<tr>
<th><input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this);" /></th>
  <th>File name</th>
  <th>Description</th>
</tr>

Answer (score 0):

Can i know a full example of your "file_folder" link? Because you only can unlink your file just in a public link.

Try to access your link "file_folder" in new tab of browser. If you can download your file it means your location is correct and your unlink script supposed to be true. But if its not download it, it means your location is not correct

Comment: yes i can download the file, the problem is when deleting the row of data from database, the file from the folder was not deleted. how can i use the unlink function properly?

Comment: FYI dont put the unlink source file with 'http' or anything similar. Just write the source from where you access the page.
For example:
dont unlink("http://www.something.com/file/any.xls")
do unlink("file/any.xls")